# How to access a radio button with an array in its name in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, radio-button

I've the following code in my HTML page:

```
<input id="user_profile_provide_veterinary_transportation_Yes" name="user_profile[provide_veterinary_transportation]" type="radio" value="Yes">
```

Before making changes to the site, I was having its name like `name=provide_veterinary_transportation`, and the following way, I was accessing it in jQuery:

```
$("input[type=radio][name=provide_veterinary_transportation]");
```

But now, since it's changed to `name=user_profile[provide_veterinary_transportation]`, I'm unable to find a way to access this using jQuery.

Comment: Why not use an `id` as selector?

Comment: input[name="user_profile[provide_veterinary_transportation"]

Comment: @Mr.Alien I need to pass its value into something that requires it to be in `user_profile` array on the server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[type=radio][name="user_profile[provide_veterinary_transportation]"]');
```